# Plotting Bode-Plot from an external csv in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to achieve a Plot like this:

[image: Bode]

the following Code produces this Output:

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
title=Bode diagram,
xlabel={frequency},
ylabel={amplitude},
grid=major
                    ]
\addplot[domain=1:100000]  {(60*x+10000)/(x*x + 60*x+10000)};
\end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The Problem is, that i have a *.csv File with 3 Colums. Structured like that:

[image: excel]

the file has 1000 lines, so it is a little bit bigger..
How can i achieve to Plot the magnitude/phase into 2 Plots?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the 'pgfplotstable' function (which are already loaded with pgfplot) and the 'groupplot' libary (which must be specified after the package).

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{filecontents}{pntInBode.csv}
freq,amp,phase
10,55,-0.5
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{pntInBode.csv}{\data}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=plot,
        group size=1 by 2,
        x descriptions at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0.1cm,
    },
    domain=1:100000,
    xlabel={frequency},
    xmode=log,
]
\nextgroupplot[title=Bode diagram,ylabel={amplitude},ymode=log]
\addplot[black, no marks] {(60*x+10000)/(x*x + 60*x+10000)};
\addplot[red,only marks,mark=x] table[x index=0, y index=1] {\data};
\nextgroupplot[ylabel={phase},ymin=-1]
\addplot[black, no marks] {(60*x+10000)/(x*x + 60*x+10000)};
\addplot[blue, only marks, mark=o] table[x index=0, y index=2] {\data};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]" occured. As I said, the file is 1000 Lines big.

Comment: On the one hand you could try to use the 'each nth point' or 'samples' commands to reduce the data points, which will be used for the plots. On the other hand you may want to decrease the input file itself or increase your memory size (see other questions for more information) or switch to LuaLaTeX. However, i think that problem is independent from your original question about the plot.

Comment: @adaptive Do you have try to compile with LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

If your function is only a combination of simple functions (first order, second order, integration, ...) you can in addition to the bodegraph package, use the online application http://bode.allais.eu/
which generates the code to draw Bode diagrams.

[image]